# How to find @username for tunneling SSH to the VMs behind Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, ssh, azureportal

I can able to view Spark Cluster Master & Worker nodes hostname but I couldn't find username to log in on SSH

For Example(In terminal): 
ssh username@hostname_or_Ip

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you cannot SSH on Azure Databricks.

**Note:** Azure Databricks integrated with Azure Active Directory – So, Azure Databricks users are only regular AAD users.

- Azure Active Directory users can be used directly in Azure Databricks
  for al user-based access control (Clusters, jobs, Notebooks etc.).
- Azure Databricks has delegated user authentication to AAD enabling
  single-sign on (SSO) and unified authentication.
- Notebooks and their outputs, are stored in the Databricks account.
  However, AAD based access control ensures that only authorized users 
  can access them.

[image]

For more details, refer “[Azure Databricks Preview Documentation”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/).